# Slideshow module in D7

Tags: 7, media, javascript

Is there any slideshow module in D7 similar to this one - http://www.cnngo.com/shanghai/life/facekini-woman-chinas-latest-beach-sensation-680659

In D6 the Views Slideshow can do this but not sure in D7. Any ideas?

Comment: Views slideshow hasn't changed in d7 very much and can do that setup still.

Answer (score 1):

The views slide show in Drupal 7 in my opinion is even better than in 6 as it start right of the bat with the jQuery Cycle library and that alone will give you a lot of nice effects plus all the extra tools like pagers, counters and controls.

Check the last tutorials on the modules pages page to learn more about the installation and configuration including the thumbnail pagers.

Comment: Thanks Adam...I actually having problem got this error `[cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1 jquery.cycle.all.min.js:28
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paused' of undefined `